# Reducing sub-steps displayed on Spring Batch Admin UI when total partition count is high

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I have a spring batch process which has a step that is partitioned. I need to keep 100 partitions with max 10 threads running concurrently.

Since 100 partitions are there, Spring Batch Admin UI will display 100 sub-steps in the User Interface. As this may not be readable, is it possible to reduce total number of sub-steps to 10 (which is equivalent to max threads)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box.  It's open source so you're free to customize as you need, but the out of the box functionality is to display all step executions.